# LCD Laptop \ Tablet

Tags: laptop, tablet

Shot in the dark here but is anyone aware of any laptops or tablets which have a pure LCD (Old LCD screen without the LED backlight).

Now let me explain why...

I have a brother who suffers from a rare eye condition which is worsened by LED screens. (uveitis) 
So essentially we are hunting for a device which he is still able to use as he is unaffected by LCD screen technology.

As you can imagine with everything going LED this leaves him with very little options.

Essentially we cannot afford to be fussy but it would be great if the device is at least a high spec i5.

Comment: Just to be clear, will a screen that is backlit with a cold-cathode fluorescent lamp (CCFL) rather than LEDs be acceptable?  Or does he have a more general photophobia or light sensitivity, meaning that perhaps you are looking for something along the lines of what you would find in the Gameboy Advance?  Do sunglasses or computer glasses help?  Do you think a device with a [built-in projector](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/tablets/lenovo/yoga-tablet-series/yoga-tab-3-pro-10/) would work?

Comment: Hi there thanks for the reply he is 100% fine with regular LCD TV's and monitors. I believe the LED strobes more or something like that so if i can get hold of something that still has LCD and is at least i5 that would be great.